# Proof that if you have two splitting fields for the same polynomial and one of them is contained in a radical extension, then so is the other one.

Tags: abstract-algebra, extension-field, splitting-field, galois-extensions

Let $E|K$ and $E'|K$ be splitting fields of a polynomial $f \in K[X]$.
Prove that if $E$ is contained in a radical extension of $K$, then so is $E'$.

My "proof": 
$E \cong K(R(f))$, where $R(f)$ denotes the set of roots in some closure. Splitting fields are unique up to isomorphism. Therefore also $E' \cong K(R(f))$. By assumption $K(R(f)) \subset F$ for some radical extension $F|K$. And we're done.

Clearly there must be something wrong and I feel very confused myself by my solution.

I get very confused by questions about splitting fields and I'm unsure if that's the right way to think of them.

I'd really appreciate any help.

Comment: But two splitting fields of the same polynomial, over the same base field, will be isomorphic. Isn’t this what you want to use?

Comment: @Lubin Yes, that is what I meant to use in my attempt.